# Operation on two time series data

Tags: r

I have two zoo objects as
z1

```
                T1      T2      T3
2013-01-18      20      15      21
2013-01-20      30      18      17
2013-01-21      10      21      24
2013-01-22      15      17      15
2013-01-23      18      16      18
```

z2

```
                T1          T2          T3
2013-01-18      0.05        0.01        0.09
2013-01-20      0.02        0.05        0.06
2013-01-21      0.06        0.02        0.07
2013-01-22      0.07        0.06        0.08
2013-01-23      0.01        0.06        0.05
```

I am trying to get output as

```
                T1                 T2                   T3
2013-01-18      myfunc(20,0.05)     myfunc(15,0.01)     myfunc(21,0.09)
2013-01-20      myfunc(30,0.02)     myfunc(18,0.05)     myfunc(17,0.06)
2013-01-21      myfunc(10,0.06)     myfunc(21,0.02)     myfunc(24,0.07)
2013-01-22      myfunc(15,0.07)     myfunc(17,0.06)     myfunc(15,0.08)
2013-01-23      myfunc(18,0.01)     myfunc(16,0.06)     myfunc(18,0.05)
```

It seems like using apply/rollapply will do the task, but as I am new to R, I could not do this.

Update
Lets say I have a dataframe also

```
Name Quantity Base
 T1   100      T3
 T2   150      T3
 T3   160      T3
```

And output required like this

```
                T1                     T2                   T3
2013-01-18      myfunc(20,0.05,100)     myfunc(20,0.01,150)     myfunc(20,0.09,160)
2013-01-20      myfunc(30,0.02,100)     myfunc(30,0.05,150)     myfunc(30,0.06,160)
2013-01-21      myfunc(10,0.06,100)     myfunc(10,0.02,150)     myfunc(10,0.07,160)
2013-01-22      myfunc(15,0.07,100)     myfunc(15,0.06,150)     myfunc(15,0.08,160)
2013-01-23      myfunc(18,0.01,100)     myfunc(18,0.06,150)     myfunc(18,0.05,160)
```

Please note that now 1st parameter is also based on Base column of dataframe

Comment: Actually I just showed the simple example but the result I want to use will be based on user defined function which will not be x*y.

Comment: Perhaps `z3 <- z1;  z3[] <- mapply(function(x,y,i) myfunc(x[,i], y[,i]), list(z1), list(z2), seq_len(ncol(z1)))`

Comment: It worked. Just one more concern. In the same way in the same line can we map to a dataframe also. dataframe is as name, quantity\n T1, 100\nT2,150\nT3,250. I also want to pass this also.

Comment: It is now updated.  Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
z3 <- z1
z3[] <- mapply(function(x,y,i) myfunc(x[,i], y[,i]), 
                 list(z1), list(z2), seq_len(ncol(z1)))
```

#### Update

If there is only one data.frame ("df1") and needs to pass this to `myfunc`

```
z3[] <- mapply(function(x,y,z, i) myfunc(x[,i], y[,i], z),
     list(z1), list(z2), split(df1$quantity, df1$name), 
                                  seq_len(ncol(z1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution it works. And I also made changes to first parameter of my function. So can you take a look. I am accepting it as it is working flawless.

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish  Thanks for the update.  You may need to check the output of `split(df1$quantity, df1$name)`.  I would imagine that to come out in the same order `T1, T2, T3` unless the name column is factor and its levels are ordered differently.

Comment: I have simplified the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024929/operation-on-multiple-zoo-object-with-data-frame

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish Regarding the one in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997341/copy-columns-of-zoo-object-on-the-basis-of-a-condition-in-data-frame, do you have a better example