# Copy columns of zoo object on the basis of a condition in data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and a zoo objet as

```
                T1      T2      T3  
2013-01-18      20      15      21
2013-01-20      30      18      17
2013-01-21      10      21      24
2013-01-22      15      17      15
2013-01-23      18      16      18


Name    DoApply Base
T1      YES     T3
T2      YES     T3
T3      NO      T3
T4      YES     T5
T5      NO      T5
```

Base dataframe can have more values of Name.
Now on the basis of whether doApply is yes I want to copy value from its base column. Output like this

```
                T1      T2      T3
2013-01-18      21      21      21
2013-01-20      17      17      17
2013-01-21      24      24      24
2013-01-22      15      15      15
2013-01-23      18      18      18
```

This might be straight forward but somehow I could not get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be

```
indx <- d1$DoApply=='YES'
indx1 <- d1$Name[indx] %in% names(z)
z[, indx1] <- z[, d1$Base[indx][indx1]]
z
#           T1 T2 T3
#2013-01-18 21 21 21
#2013-01-20 17 17 17
#2013-01-21 24 24 24
#2013-01-22 15 15 15
#2013-01-23 18 18 18
```

Comment: I am getting this error (subscript) logical subscript too long.

Comment: It is working perfectly. The only part was missing in my data with reference to data shown in question is that my data has some missing columns as compared to df and vice versa. That is why logical script too long error.

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish  Have you corrected that error?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes, I have applied the filter and replaced NA with FALSE to correct the logical script