# Operation on multiple zoo object with data frame

Tags: r

I have two time series (zoo) objects and a data frame
z1

```
z1 <- structure(c(400L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 120L,400L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 120L,400L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 120L
,400L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 120L), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T6"
)), index = structure(c(15723, 15725, 15726, 15727, 15728), class = "Date"), 
class = "zoo")



            T1  T2  T3  T6
2013-01-18 400 400 400 400
2013-01-20 125 125 125 125
2013-01-21 125 125 125 125
2013-01-22 125 125 125 125
2013-01-23 120 120 120 120
```

z2

```
z2 <- structure(c(40L, 12L, 25L, 15L, 10L,40L, 25L, 15L, 123L, 190L,150L, 115L, 155L, 105L, 80L
,40L, 425L, 225L, 115L, 20L), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T6"
)), index = structure(c(15723, 15725, 15726, 15727, 15728), class = "Date"), 
class = "zoo")


            T1  T2  T3  T6
2013-01-18 40  40 150  40
2013-01-20 12  25 115 425
2013-01-21 25  15 155 225
2013-01-22 15 123 105 115
2013-01-23 10 190  80  20
```

df

```
l <- "Name, DOB, TypeOfApply, House
        T1, 2008-12-16, sync,44
        T2, 2008-12-15, sync,54
        T3, 2008-12-19, async,34
        T4, 2008-12-18, async,84
        T5, 2008-12-11, sync,94"

df <- read.csv(text = l)
```

I want to apply a formula(function I created to use "calc") bsaed on condition that TypeOfApply == "sync". Z1 and Z2 is going to have same no of rows and columns.

```
calc(z1,z2,df$DOB-2013-01-18,df$House)
                    T1                                  T2                                           T3  T6
2013-01-18 calc(400,40,((2008-12-16)-(2013-01-18)),44) calc(400,40,((2008-12-15)-(2013-01-18)),54)  400 400
2013-01-20 calc(125,12,((2008-12-16)-(2013-01-20)),44) calc(400,25,((2008-12-15)-(2013-01-20)),54)  125 125
2013-01-21 calc(125,25,((2008-12-16)-(2013-01-21)),44) calc(400,15,((2008-12-15)-(2013-01-21)),54)  125 125
2013-01-22 calc(125,15,((2008-12-16)-(2013-01-22)),44) calc(400,123,((2008-12-15)-(2013-01-22)),54) 125 125
2013-01-23 calc(120,10,((2008-12-16)-(2013-01-23)),44) calc(400,190,((2008-12-15)-(2013-01-23)),54) 120 120
```

So, in this code T1 and T2 will have formula to be applied, but others will not
T3 - Type of Apply is async
T5 - Does not exist in z1 and z2
T6 - Does not exist in df

**Update**
Sequence of names in df may be different. So it may be like T2, T1, T3, T5, T4

Just as sample calc function

```
 calc <- function(x,y,z,v)
 {
   val <- x+y+(z/365)+v
   return(val)
 }
```

Comment: can you apply your function on a single column of Z1, Z2? Also do you want the output to be one dataframe containing both Z1 and Z2 i.e. `rbind` the new Z1 and Z2 tables? And it's kind of hard to help unless we know how `calc` works...

Comment: Output will be a zoo object with time series, same as z1 and z2. Actually I want to use EuropianOption function from RQuantLib just used calc in place of it.

Comment: calc/EuropeanOption takes difference of two dates  as "no of days/365" fractional year

Comment: @akrun Not much impact of calc in this question scenario. It can simply sum all the parameters for simplicity.

Comment: z2 is derived from z1 so all rows and columns are same in both zoo object just the values are different. While df can have more/less names than columns of any zoo object.

Comment: Columns of z1/z2 is same as 1st column of df. Also DOB and House is also part of df. For T1 DOB is 2008-12-16 is same throughout the span of time range in output and in the same way House is also same for T1 from 1st row of df

Comment: No, its simple decimal  numbers. Even "df$DOB-2013-01-18" will be as no of days/365. Example x <- calc(400.05, 0.54,32/365,44). x will also contain some decimal number such as 45.06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I am using `str_trim` as there are leading/lagging spaces in "df" columns.  Converted the "factor" column "DOB' to "Date" class, created a "indx" based on the condition that of "TypeOfApply" elements are "sync" and corresponding "Name" elements are present in the column names of "z1".  This "indx" is used for subsetting the "df", as well as "z1", and "z2".  Then use "Map" function and get the corresponding columns of "z1", "z2", elements of "df1$DOB", "df1$House", which can be used as inputs in the "calc" function.

```
library(stringr)
indx <- intersect(with(df,str_trim(Name[str_trim(TypeOfApply)=='sync'])),
              colnames(z1))

df1 <- df[str_trim(as.character(df$Name)) %in% indx,c(2,4)]
df1$DOB <- as.Date(str_trim(df1$DOB))
Map(function(u,v,x,y) calc(u,v, x-'2013-01-18', y),
 as.data.frame(z1[,indx]), as.data.frame(z2[,indx]), df1$DOB, df1$House)
```

#### Update

Using the `calc` function from OP's post

```
z3 <- z1[,indx]
index <- as.Date('2013-01-18')
z3[] <- mapply(calc, as.data.frame(z1[,indx]), 
    as.data.frame(z2[,indx]), df1$DOB-index, df1$House)
z3
#               T1       T2
#2013-01-18 479.9068 489.9041
#2013-01-20 176.9068 199.9041
#2013-01-21 189.9068 189.9041
#2013-01-22 179.9068 297.9041
#2013-01-23 169.9068 359.9041
```

Suppose, if I change the order of "df" rows

```
set.seed(24)
df <- df[sample(1:nrow(df)),]
```

Then, the "Map" list elements will be in the same order as "indx", for example,

```
indx
#[1] "T2" "T1"
df1
#         DOB House
#2 2008-12-15    54
#1 2008-12-16    44

 Map(function(u,v,x,y)  u, as.data.frame(z1[,indx]), 
   as.data.frame(z2[,indx]), df1$DOB, df1$House)
 #$T2
 #[1] 400 125 125 125 120

 #$T1
 #[1] 400 125 125 125 120
```

Comment: I believe, instead of x-'2013-01-18' it should be like "x-index". Any way to do this. And I believe output should be zoo object, but not getting it, currently looking into it.

Comment: Not sure I understand it correctly as `x` is `Date` class and the `2013-01-18` should be also Date.  May be you need to wrap it in a function?.  The `Map` output would be a list, but it all depends upon how the `calc` behaves.  As I don't have access to it, I can't say much.

Comment: I mean instead of '2013-01-18' as a fixed date, it should be varying based on date for which values from z1/z2 are picked

Comment: In that case, you could make that a function `fun1 <- function( index){Map(function(u,v,x,y) calc(u,v, x-index, y),
 as.data.frame(z1[,indx]), as.data.frame(z2[,indx]), df1$DOB, df1$House)}`  Also, you can use other values as input in the function.

Comment: Updated the question about calc. Its not of much importance as I said earlier.

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish  In the calc you showed, there is no `x-index`.  Anyway, try using `fun1`